# SignalR uninstall artifacts

Tags: c#, signalr, nuget

So i tried to install the signalR to my project, went through all the stuff i needed, then switch to my master branch (discarded all changes) and run my website.

I keep getting this error

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

although i do not have any references to Owin left in my project or any Startup.cs file or anything at all. There's no changes in my commit right now and yet i have this error.

I removed the package with -RemoveDependencies via NuGetPM.

Comment: try clearing the nuget cache, clean the solution, and then rebuild

Answer (score 0):

There must be some remnants. What i do in such cases is to completely empty the directory and do a fresh check-out. As you have discarded all changes this will work i guess.

Comment: Completely empty what directory? Repository? Oo